# Laravel hasone relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, one-to-one

I am trying to use hasone relation but getting null error. below is my code

**User Model:**

```
  function profile()
{
    $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

**Profile Model:**

```
   function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Register Controller**

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user =  User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    if($user) {

        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->name = 'Fake Name';
        $profile->father = 'Fake Father';
        $user->profile()->save($profile);
    }

    return $user;

}
```

> Error: Call to a member function save() on null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change User.php to

```
  function profile()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
  }
```

You need to return the relationship instance.