# how can I fetch data in data from 2 table using with hasOne relation in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch all data from users and users_profile table with the corresponding id and user_id with using the hasOne relation, But I don't know how to make the condition to fetch data from the two tables with using the corresponding id and user_id

controller

```
public function index()
{

    $profile = Userprofile::with('users')->get();
    return view("admin.allusers",compact("profile"));

}
```

in user model

```
public function usersprofiles(){
    return $this->hasOne(Userprofile::class);
}
```

in Userprofile model

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please refer to answers to similar questions. For example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422462/laravel-hasone-relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the code below:

```
public function usersprofiles(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

That's assuming you have a field `user_id` in your `users_profiles` that correspond to field `id` in your `users` table.

But since you are fetching the profiles of users, your `index()` should be:

```
$profiles = User::with('usersprofiles')->get();
return view("admin.allusers", compact("profiles"));
```

And your `User` Model

```
public function usersprofiles(){
   return $this->hasOne(Userprofile::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

And your UserProfile Mode

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
}
```

Hope it helps.